# Java Stream - Combine filter and collect

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

```
ColumnFamily column = tokens.getColumnFamilies().stream()
    .filter(family -> family.getName().equals("this_family"))
    .findAny()
    .get();

Map<String, String> tokenized = column.getColumns().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Column::getQualifier,
        Column::getValue
    ));
```

Is there a way I can combine these two streams into one? I am using the first stream to filter and find on my nested list, and using the second stream to create a map based on the result of the stream. I am wondering if there's a way I could have done this using a single stream.

Something like this

```
Map<String, String> tokenized = tokens.getColumnFamilies().stream()
    .filter(family -> family.getName().equals("this_family"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        //
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to get nested `Stream` and flatten the structure:

```
Map<String, String> tokenized = tokens.getColumnFamilies().stream()
    .filter(family -> family.getName().equals("this_family"))
    .limit(1)  // equivalent of findAny
    .flatMap(cf -> cf.getColumns().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Column::getQualifier,
        Column::getValue
    ));
```

Comment: If there are multiple families that pass the filter, the resulting map will be a merge of them. Do you need a choice equivalent to `findAny()`?

Comment: @saka1029 nice catch. adding `limit(1)` would be the equivalent of `findAny`

Comment: Hi thank you for your answers. I just have additional question, If ever that I would like to return a list instead of a Map<T,T> and do some workarounds with the value. 

Should I do `.flatMap(.stream()).map().collect();` or `.flatMap(.stream().map()).collect();` I actually tried both, and both is working. I am just not sure what is the better implementation or there is any other appropriate implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @jawsh a list of *what*?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Optional#map()` and combine

```
Map<String, String> tokenized = tokens.getColumnFamilies().stream()
                    .filter(family -> family.getName().equals("this_family"))
                    .findAny()
                    .map(cf -> cf.getColumns().stream()).get()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Column::getQualifier, Column::getValue));
```